# Updating json column using window cumulative via pyspark

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've been trying to update a series of JSON blobs via Pyspark, SparkSQL, and Pandas but have been unsuccessful. Here is what the data looks like:

```
#+---+---------+------------------------------------------+
#|ID |Timestamp|Properties                                |
#+---+---------+------------------------------------------+
#|a  |7        |{"a1": 5, "a2": 8}                        |
#|b  |12       |{"b1": 36, "b2": "u", "b3": 17, "b8": "c"}|
#|a  |8        |{"a2": 4}                                 |
#|a  |10       |{"a3": "z", "a4": "t"}                    |
#|a  |5        |{"a1": 3, "a2": 12, "a4": "r"}            |
#|b  |20       |{"b2": "k", "b3": 9}                      |
#|b  |14       |{"b8": "y", "b3": 2}                      |
#+---+---------+------------------------------------------+
```

I want a query that will partition the rows by the `ID` field and sort it by the `Timestamp` field. After this the `Properties` field would cumulatively get merged in each partition to create a new column `New Props`. So the output would be this:

```
#+---+---------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+------+
#|ID |Timestamp|Properties                                |New_Props                                 |rownum|
#+---+---------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+------+
#|a  |5        |{"a1": 3, "a2": 12, "a4": "r"}            |{"a1": 3, "a2": 12, "a4": "r"}            |1     |
#|a  |7        |{"a1": 5, "a2": 8}                        |{"a1": 5, "a2": 8, "a4": "r"}             |2     |
#|a  |8        |{"a2": 4}                                 |{"a1": 5, "a2": 4, "a4": "r"}             |3     |
#|a  |10       |{"a3": "z", "a4": "t"}                    |{"a1": 5, "a2": 4, "a3": "z", "a4": "t"}  |4     |
#|b  |12       |{"b1": 36, "b2": "u", "b3": 17, "b8": "c"}|{"b1": 36, "b2": "u", "b3": 17, "b8": "c"}|1     |
#|b  |14       |{"b8": "y", "b3": 2}                      |{"b1": 36, "b2": "u", "b3": 2, "b8": "y"} |2     |
#|b  |20       |{"b2": "k", "b3": 9}                      |{"b1": 36, "b2": "k", "b3": 9, "b8": "y"} |3     |
#+---+---------+------------------------------------------+------+------------------------------------------+
```

Formula: Starting from `rownum` 2, get the `New Props` column value of the previous row (`rownum` 1) and update it with the value in column `Properties` of the current row (`rownum` 2).

I tried using the `LAG` function but I can't use a column that I'm currently calculating within the function itself.

To create the `Next Props` column I tried this CASE statement but it did not work:

```
CASE
    WHEN rownum != 1 THEN concat(properties, LAG(next_props, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY contentid ORDER BY updateddatetime))
    ELSE next_props
END AS new_props
```

I've been trying different things for awhile but I'm stuck. I can probably do it with a for loop and the python `dict.update()` function but I'm worried about efficiency. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using higher-order functions on array and map columns:

1. get previous `Properties` for each row using `lag` and convert both the previous and current row `Properties` into map type
2. using `collect_list` function over window, get cumulative array of previous row `Properties`
3. add the current row `Properties` to the resulting array and use `aggregate` to concatenate inner maps using `map_concat`. From your example, it seems that the update operation consists on simply adding the new keys, so before concat, we filter the already existing keys using `map_filter` function
4. use `to_json` to get json string from the aggregated map and drop intermediary columns

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("Timestamp")

df1 = df.withColumn("rownum", F.row_number().over(w)) \
    .withColumn("prev_prop_map", F.from_json(F.lag("Properties").over(w), "map<string,string>")) \
    .withColumn("current_prop_map", F.from_json("Properties", "map<string,string>")) \
    .withColumn("cumulative_prev_props", F.collect_list("prev_prop_map").over(w)) \
    .withColumn(
        "New_Props",
        F.to_json(F.aggregate(
            F.concat(F.array("current_prop_map"), F.reverse(F.col("cumulative_prev_props"))),
            F.expr("cast(map() as map<string,string>)"),
            lambda acc, x: F.map_concat(
                acc,
                F.map_filter(x, lambda k, _: ~F.array_contains(F.map_keys(acc), k))
            )
        ))
).drop("prev_prop_map", "current_prop_map", "cumulative_prev_props")


df1.show(truncate=False)
#+---+---------+------------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------+
#|ID |Timestamp|Properties                                |rownum|New_Props                              |
#+---+---------+------------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------+
#|a  |5        |{"a1": 3, "a2": 12, "a4": "r"}            |1     |{"a1":"3","a2":"12","a4":"r"}          |
#|a  |7        |{"a1": 5, "a2": 8}                        |2     |{"a1":"5","a2":"8","a4":"r"}           |
#|a  |8        |{"a2": 4}                                 |3     |{"a2":"4","a1":"5","a4":"r"}           |
#|a  |10       |{"a3": "z", "a4": "t"}                    |4     |{"a3":"z","a4":"t","a2":"4","a1":"5"}  |
#|b  |12       |{"b1": 36, "b2": "u", "b3": 17, "b8": "c"}|1     |{"b1":"36","b2":"u","b3":"17","b8":"c"}|
#|b  |14       |{"b8": "y", "b3": 2}                      |2     |{"b8":"y","b3":"2","b1":"36","b2":"u"} |
#|b  |20       |{"b2": "k", "b3": 9}                      |3     |{"b2":"k","b3":"9","b8":"y","b1":"36"} |
#+---+---------+------------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------+
```

---

If you prefer using SQL query, here's the equivalent SparkSQL:

```sql
WITH props AS (
    SELECT  *,
            row_number() over(partition by ID order by Timestamp) AS rownum,
            from_json(lag(Properties) over(partition by ID order by Timestamp), 'map<string,string>') AS prev_prop_map,
            from_json(Properties, 'map<string,string>') AS current_prop_map
    FROM    props_tb
),  cumulative_props AS (
    SELECT  *,
            collect_list(prev_prop_map) over(partition by ID order by Timestamp) AS cumulative_prev_props
    FROM    props 
)

SELECT  ID,
        Timestamp,
        Properties,
        aggregate(
            concat(array(current_prop_map), reverse(cumulative_prev_props)),
            cast(map() as map<string,string>),
            (acc, x) -> map_concat(acc, map_filter(x, (k,v) -> ! array_contains(map_keys(acc), k)))
        ) AS New_Props,
        rownum
FROM    cumulative_props
```

Comment: Thank you so much man, this worked like a charm! I hadn't ever used/heard of some of those functions like `collect_list()`. To get the output I needed, I just had to wrap the `aggregate()` in a `to_json()` function to get the final result as a string again.

Also was there a reason for adding the `reverse()` function? I took it out and the result was still correct.